# Increase tooltip character limit - md-angular tooltip

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

Well,

i`m trying to use angular material design tooltip directive, but im facing an issue due to my tooltip message size, that is showing entirely.

I tried looking into md repository, but couldnt find out how to configure it

this is the code i`m trying:

```html
<md-content >
  <md-button class="badge-blue">
    <span>?</span>
      <md-tooltip>
      This is the tootip message that i need to see, without ... 
    </md-tooltip>
  </md-button>
<md-content>
```

The content and button styles are setting width to 100%.

Using the message above, i can only see: "This is the tootip message that i ne..."

I really appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply adjust/override the stylesheets:

Html:

```
<md-content >
  <md-button class="badge-blue">
    <span>?</span>
      <md-tooltip class="large">
      This is the tootip message that i need to see, without ... 
    </md-tooltip>
  </md-button>
<md-content>
```

Css:

```
md-tooltip.large .md-content {
    max-width: 500px; // Or whatever you need.
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOvWGb

Answer (score 1):

That is the maximum size you can have for the time being, There is already a request made to make this on the angular-material.

[`Make md-tooltip width a bit larger`](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/656)

Answer (score 0):

the solutions i saw would only make the tooltip longer but still on one line.
i prefered override the white-space on css:

```
md-tooltip .md-content{

  white-space: inherit;

}
```